# react-datepicker and react-hooks-form get value displayed in datepicker without time zone

Tags: react-datepicker, react-hook-form

I am using react-datepicker and react-hook-form. But my picker add time zone to the result:

[image]
Is there anyway to ensure that the picker just returns the value provided in the picker with out adding timezone?

```
const FormDatePicker = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <Label for="exampleEmail">{props.label}</Label>
      <Controller
        as={
          <DatePicker
            isClearable
            name={props.name}
            className={"form-control"}
            showTimeSelect
            timeFormat="HH:mm"
            timeIntervals={15}
            timeCaption="time"
            dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy H:mm"
            autoComplete="Off"
          />
        }
        control={props.control}
        rules={{ required: false }}
        valueName="selected"
        onChange={([date]) => date}
        name={props.name}
        placeholderText="Select date"
        defaultValue={null}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: pretty sure you can, as long as you return the correct value at the Controller

Comment: I updated with code. Is it a time zone you set on the picker?

Comment: no, we don't. console.log onChange={([date]) => date} the date in there.

Comment: Yes but as you in the image the value differs from what I picked. So there is some time zone correlation.

Comment: yea, i saw that. that's why i asked to check the onChange method. maybe it's returning that value. you probably need to return the version without the timezone.